# how to avoid php script adding the wrong location in a script?

Tags: php, html, ajax

So I'm using ajax content, thats fine but the php script I'm using is adding the link of the directory I wanna show onto the link I'm looking at. So basically;

here the php:

```
<?PHP
$category = "8";
$template = "Archives";
include("admin/show_news.php");
?>
```

the link is:
www.example.com/#page

but the script is making it like:
www.example.com/#page/admin/show_news.php

when it should be gaining the information from;
www.example.com/admin/show_news.php

how do I edit the script code to make it so it finds the correct directory?

Answer (score 0):

Change `include("admin/show_news.php");`
to `include("/admin/show_news.php");`

The difference is the *forward slash* added at the beginning of the path, which interpreted as the link path starting from the root.

Comment: What is the resulting script when you add the forward slash?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
include("admin/show_news.php");
```

To

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/admin/show_news.php");
```

Comment: www.michaeldylanedwards.co.uk/#archives